# What is the syntax to model an array of opening times in HTML and angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, mongoose-schema

I have tried everything and have not been able to make it work. I am trying to POST an object to the server which must contain an array of opening times. The array should be an array of objects and each object should have the three fields day, start and end. Ideally this is how I want it to be represented.

```
opening_hours = [
{day: "Sunday", start: "11", end: "15"},
{day: "Monday", start: "8", end: "19"},
{day: "Tuesday", start: "8", end: "19"},
{day: "Wednesday", start: "8", end: "19"},
{day: "Thursday", start: "8", end: "19"},
{day: "Friday", start: "8", end: "19"},
{day: "Saturday", start: "5", end: "17"},
];
```

That way you can loop through the array and output the opening times for a specific day.

I tried representing it in HTML using a table by having a row for each day and each row has three input fields; the day is hardcoded using a hidden field and two text inputs for the times. The HTML is included below:

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>DAY</th>
    <th>OPEN</th>
    <th>CLOSE</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>SUN<input type="hidden" value="Sunday" ng-model="rCtrl.office.opening_hours[0].day"></td>
      <td><input type="text" ng-model="rCtrl.office.opening_hours[0].open" required></td>
      <td><input type="text" ng-model="rCtrl.office.opening_hours[0].close" required></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>MON<input type="hidden" value="Monday" ng-model="rCtrl.office.opening_hours[1].day"></td>
      <td><input type="text" ng-model="rCtrl.office.opening_hours[1].open" required></td>
      <td><input type="text" ng-model="rCtrl.office.opening_hours[1].close" required></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>TUES<input type="hidden" value="Tuesday" ng-model="rCtrl.office.opening_hours[2].day"></td>
      <td><input type="text" ng-model="rCtrl.office.opening_hours[2].open" required></td>
      <td><input type="text" ng-model="rCtrl.office.opening_hours[2].close" required></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>WED<input type="hidden" value="Wednesday" ng-model="rCtrl.office.opening_hours[3].day"></td>
      <td><input type="text" ng-model="rCtrl.office.opening_hours[3].open" required></td>
      <td><input type="text" ng-model="rCtrl.office.opening_hours[3].close" required></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>THURS<input type="hidden" value="Thursday" ng-model="rCtrl.office.opening_hours[4].day"></td>
      <td><input type="text" ng-model="rCtrl.office.opening_hours[4].open" required></td>
      <td><input type="text" ng-model="rCtrl.office.opening_hours[4].close" required></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>FRI<input type="hidden" value="Friday" ng-model="rCtrl.office.opening_hours[5].day"></td>
      <td><input type="text" ng-model="rCtrl.office.opening_hours[5].open"></td>
      <td><input type="text" ng-model="rCtrl.office.opening_hours[5].close"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>SAT<input type="hidden" value="Saturday" ng-model="rCtrl.office.opening_hours[6].day"></td>
      <td><input type="text" ng-model="rCtrl.office.opening_hours[6].open"></td>
      <td><input type="text" ng-model="rCtrl.office.opening_hours[6].close"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Note: I am using Controller as syntax, rCtrl refers to the controller controlling the HTML, office is the object that binds form data to the Controller and opening hours is supposed to be the array of day objects.**

In my controller now I have tried to display the values that are in what is supposed to be the `opening_hours` array but it displays as an object containing seven objects and uses the index as a property for each object as below:

```
opening_hours = {
0: {open: 9, close: 17},
1: {open: 9, close: 17},
2: {open: 9, close: 17},
3: {open: 9, close: 17},
4: {open: 9, close: 17},
5: {open: 9, close: 17},
6: {open: 9, close: 17},
}
```

If I tried outputting a day using array index syntax like:

`console.log(rModel.restaurant.opening_hours[0]);`

It outputs the object at the property 0.

I have tried initalising the array in my controller to an empty array but I get a undefined error when I reload the page. This is what I tried:

`var rModel = this;`
`rModel.office.opening_hours = [];`

**Again note the `rModel` refers to the controller, it is initialised using `this` to avoid me using the `$scope`.**

What am I doing wrong? Even though I have indexed each day in the HTML it still shows as an object. Also it completely ignores the hidden fields with their values hardcoded to a specific day. I am aware I can change my Schema to use an object instead of an array and that would get it working but I want to be able to loop through the opening_hours array in a native way. Finally my Schema is included below.

```
var new_branch= new OfficeSchema({
    name:                   {type: String, unique: true},
    id_name:                {type: String, lowercase: true, unique: true},
    phone:                  {type: String},
    logo:                   {type: String},
    images:                 [{type: String}],
    country:                {type: String},
    description:            {type: String},
    review:                 {type: Number},
    opening_hours:          [{day: String, open: Number, close: Number}],
});
```

How can I get it to be in the format I would like an array of objects with the three properties `day`, `open` and `close`.

Comment: Why don't you use `ng-repeat`?

Comment: In one place you use open/close, in another place you use start/end. I'm not sure if that would affect anything in this case, just thought it was worth pointing out.

Comment: @Mistalis how would I do that? I know I can use it for a array that has values to display them but how would I do it for an empty and uninitialised array?

Comment: @Zack, the first array with start/end is just to display the format I would like the array to be in. Throughout my HTML, Mongoose Schema and angular code I use open/close.

Comment: Might want to check if your object is be casted to the right type?

Comment: @JDavila what do you mean by that? What type should I be casting it to?

Comment: @Courtney, To be honest, am not sure, if you have array objects that need to be displayed as string, then they should probably be cast to a string, from the array.